# Running NodeJS commands and Linux cmd in Crontab

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running an EC2 AWS instance, I have a range of commands and scripts that run well but will not execute within a crontab. Here are the contents of the Crontab:

```
15 03 * * * pythonscript1.py
45 03 * * * pythonscript2.py
00 05 * * * gsjson 1z5OlqsyU5N2ze1JYHJssfe1LpKNvsr4j8TDGnvyuaDZ gsheet.json
05 05 * * * s3cmd put gsheet.json -P -f s3://mybucket772
```

Do I need the path of the python program within EC2? gsjson was installed as a NPM package using NodeJS and S3cmd is a command line tool I installed.

https://s1.postimg.org/nu4zfb22n/ec2-filetree.jpg

I assume I might the programs path within cron but I'm not sure what command I need to get this. Or maybe I should the wrap the last 2 commands in a .js file and point to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending an entire bank holiday wrestling with this. Here was the solution, looks so easy now but not when you are wrestling with it:

I edited the ec2-user cron using the command: `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`, whilst logged in as the ec2-user. To create my cron job.

The main problem I had was not having the following at the top of my crontab

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

as these point to the location of gsjson and s3cmd.

However, the Python scripts still wouldn't work as the path for those was usr/bin. So we needed the absolute path for both the location of Python and the script. So below was the final cron contents, the working solution. Thanks for the others input on the question too.

Ensure the scripts are 0755 permissions.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin

15 03 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/pythonscript1.py
45 03 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/pythonscript2.py
00 05 * * * gsjson 1z5OlqsyU5N2ze1JYHJssfe1LpKNvsr4j8TDGnvyuaDZ gsheet.json
05 05 * * * s3cmd put gsheet.json -P -f s3://mybucket772
```

**Some other useful commands too when configuring:**

```
cat /var/spool/mail/ec2-user
```

Enables you to view your error emails within the CLI

```
crontab -l
```

(Display your crontab file.)

```
crontab -e
```

(Edit your crontab file, or create one if it doesn't already exist)

```
sudo service crond status
```

(gives current status)

```
which python
```

(gives your path)

Answer (score 0):

Without further digging in your setup it should work when using absolute paths, i.e.:

```
15 03 * * * /home/ec2-user/pythonscript1.py
```

Comment: Thoughts on those final two lines? which are commands that work in the CLI but not Cron. Would it be a case of putting the path of the programs ```/usr/local/bin/gsjson```and ```/usr/local/bin/s3cmd```

Comment: You can check this by using `su` in the cli to switch to root (which is the user which executes the cron when not explicitly set to another user) and then check if the command still works without absolute path... if it doesn't, then you can either try the absolute path or add the directory to the PATH..

Comment: I also have cron file stored in /home/ec2-user with permission of 0644. Does the cron file need to be in etc/cron.daily?

Comment: can you paste the content of `/etc/crontab`?